# Samsung's App permission monitor keeps alerting my users about my app

Tags: android, permissions, notifications, camera, samsung-mobile

My app uses a background service to stay in sync with our WS and also has access to the users' camera, location, storage and phone state. It's main function is that of barcode scanning, for which I use a 3rd party library.

Recently some of my users that have my app installed on their Samsung devices have reported that they keep getting notifications from an App Permission Monitor regarding my app. It tell's them that "-the app- has been detected using Camera". As if my app is somehow using their phones' cameras while in the background.

Is there any way for me to notify the device that my app is allowed to use the camera and that notifying the user is not needed? Or to somehow not trigger this notification?

**Note:** I don't check for camera permission or try to access it from my background service.

---

I found [a this article about how to disable the feature](https://www.howtogeek.com/332816/how-to-stop-samsungs-app-permission-monitor-from-displaying-notifications/) but that's on the users' end.